# Javascript 'THIS' value using constructor without assignment to a variable

Tags: javascript, constructor, new-operator

I am currently experimenting with constructors in Javascript and wrote some code but can't quite understand it myself

```js
function someOtherFunction() {
    new Player(0, 0);
}

function Player(x, y){

    let self = this;

    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    window.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.x++;
        self.y++;

        console.log('x:' + self.x + 'y: ' + self.y);
    });
}

someOtherFunction();
```

I have created a constructor which gets executed when using the New keyword which then sets the x and y value and also binds an event listener to the window object.

I am confused as to where new Player is actually stored and how it refers to this.x and this.y and increases its value.

I did not assign the new Player to a variable to create an object so i am not to sure what the THIS is point towards?

I didn't write:

```
let a = new Player(0, 0);
```

Which this.x would then refer to the object 'a', x property. so where does this.x refer to when i haven't assigned it to a variable and how does it keep incrementing?

I thought maybe i created a closure, but i am creating a new instance of a player inside a function which i assume get's discarded once called and executed so how is it keeping a reference to the objects x and y property without assignment to some variable.

Comment: "which i assume gets discarded once called" - your assumption is incorrect. While you haven't stored an explicit reference to your Player instance outside of the constructor, the event listener retains a reference to `self`, creating a closure which causes the instance to be retained in memory.

Answer (score 3):

> I did not assign the new Player to a variable to create an object so i am not to sure what the THIS is point towards?

Calling `new Player` creates an object.

There are two references to that object.

- `this` inside the function
- the return value of the function

You discard the latter.

You copy the former to a variable called `self`.

This is closed over by the event handler function. See [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

> Which this.x would then refer to the object 'a', x property. so where does this.x refer to when i haven't assigned it to a variable and how does it keep incrementing?

You have assigned it to a variable — `this` — just by using the `new` keyword.

> I thought maybe i created a closure

Yes

> but i am creating a new instance of a player inside a function which i assume get's discarded once called and executed

The entire point of a closure is that it keeps the variable alive inside the function that closes over it.

Comment: Oh thank you. Clears things up.. bit of a confusion on my side regarding closure. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript everything that is not a primitive type (boolean, null, number, string, undefined) is an object. So the function you create is an object.

Using `new` instantiates an instance of the Object. Each instance has an automatic `this` variable.